# golang regex split string based on keywords

Tags: regex, go, regex-group

this is my string like `findstudentbyid` Now I would split based on keywords like `find` word before `find` word and after `by` and `by`, `id`.

So golang regex pattern is `` `(?i)(^find{1})(\w+)(by{1})(\w+)` ``

I am trying split this keyword `findstudentbyid` but I have an issue and I can't find an exact result which I am finding.
my expected output is `[find student by id]` or

```
find
student
by
id
```

but I am unable to do this. I did try this [golang code](https://go.dev/play/p/bHN-TIW5VBN)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {

    txt := "findstudentbyid"
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`(?i)(^find{1})(\w+)(by{1})(\w+)`)
    split := re.Split(txt, -1)
    set := []string{}
    for i := range split {
        set = append(set, split[i])
    }

    fmt.Println(set)
}
```

Comment: Why not just https://regex101.com/r/ZS09fx/1 ? `find(.+)by(.+)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `Regexp.Split()` is the solution for your case, [according to the documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/regexp#Regexp.Split):

> The slice returned by this method consists of all the substrings of s not contained in the slice returned by FindAllString.

I guess the thing you need is finding the submatches ( like `find`, `student`, `by` and `id` ):

> Submatch 0 is the match of the entire expression, submatch 1 is the match of the first parenthesized subexpression, and so on.

So you can use the `Regexp.FindStringSubmatch()` like this:

```
fmt.Println("result: ", re.FindStringSubmatch(txt))

result: [findstudentbyid find student by id]
```

I also think that you can simplify your regex, but don't forget to put it into parentheses to handle the submatches, like the one that is pointed in the comments:

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(`(find)(.+)(by)(.+)`)
```